# What is the difference between often and oftentimes?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

What is the difference between "often" and "oftentimes"? Is there any difference between the two?

Comment: [***Oftentimes***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=often%2Coftentimes&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Coften%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Coftentimes%3B%2Cc0) is dated/archaic/dialectal/folksy/quaint. Your best bet is never to use it.

Comment: OALD labels "oftentimes" as "old use or AmE".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The placement of `oftentimes` is more restricted than that of `often`. `Oftentimes` has to precede the event it modifies. The event described happens often, but not often enough to constitute a general rule.

Good:

> **Oftentimes**, Henry will find himself at the pub, catching up with friends.

Bad:

> Brownouts have been affecting the area lately, so save your work early and **oftentimes**.

It's not really a typical adverb, more of an introductory word. It's used much the same way that "hopefully" is used, as a modifier to the entire sentence.

> Hopefully, this explanation has been helpful to you.

Caution should be exercised when attempting to use this word. You can use `often` in place of `oftentimes`, but not vice versa. You should probably save `oftentimes` for fiction writing, if you use it at all. It's definitely a word you don't want to use too `often`.